# Как вместо внешних ключей получить названия других полей?

Tags: sql, запрос

Всем привет, есть такой запрос

```
select  B."IDGROUP",  B."IDLESSON"
        from  "GROUPSTUDING" B
              order by  B."IDGROUP"
```

Он выводит следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы вместо цифр выводило название группы и урок. Например:

```
(IDGROUP) (IDLESSON)
МС-42      Высшая математика
```

Вот так выглядит таблица с группами 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так с уроками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовать `inner join`.

Comment: `select G.NAMEGROUP, L.NAMELESSON from "GROUPSTUDING" B, "GROUPS" G, "LESSONS" L where L.ID=B.IDLESSON AND G.ID=B.IDGROUP` ?

Comment: @Chubatiy вы что, волшебник?)

Comment: @Chubatiy implicit join? Привет пришельцам из 1989!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, я теперь знаю, что существует такая штука как join :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev злые вы все :-)

Comment: Напрасный сарказм имхо. Если используется чисто внутреннее связывание, implicit join даёт более понятный текст. Да и объяснять переход от него к стороннему связыванию проще, чем от inner join - особенно в части типичных ошибок в размещении условий отбора.

Comment: тебе сначала [сюда](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/), а потом на SO